# Sinon stub callFake function not replacing original function

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

So this is the (snipped) code for a chatbot. I want to override the sendMessage() function to just echo the message argument. In this case, the original function runs and gives an error at the 2nd line of the function. Obviously, modules aren't loaded and I don't need them to. This is a test for the eventHandler to echo the right messages. Ideas?

```js
var modules = require('./modules');
console.log('[tose] Loading modules: ', Object.keys(modules));
    
function eventHandler(channel, type, data, react=()=>{}) {
  switch (type) {
    case 'new_message':
      console.log('[tose][new_message]', channel, 'from:', data.cid, 'message:', data.message);
      if (regexTemplates.testSearch.test(data.message.toLowerCase())) {
        ...
      } else {
        sendMessage(channel, data.cid, data.message);    // Basic echo message
      }
      break;
  }
}
    
// The function to be stubbed
function sendMessage(channel, cid, message) {
  console.log('[tose][send_message]', channel, 'to:', cid, 'message:', message);
  coms[channel].sendMessage(cid, message); // Getting error here thus not really stubbed
}
    
exports.eventHandler = eventHandler;
exports.sendMessage = sendMessage
```

And the test:

```js
describe('Tose core', function() {
  describe('Process messages', function() {

    before(function() {
      var stub = sinon.stub(tose, 'sendMessage').callsFake(function(channel, cid, message) {
        assert.equal(message, 'Test message');
        return message
      });
    });

    after(function() {
      tose.sendMessage.restore();
    });

    it('should echo messages', function() {
      var data = {message: 'Test message'}
      tose.eventHandler('test', 'new_message', data)
      assert(tose.sendMessage.calledOnce);
    });

  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that when you use `Sinon` to stub an object's function, you're stubbing that (and only that) object's function.

---

Your code (the first code block) is using the local definition of the `sendMessage` function.

When you `stub` the `tose` object (in the second code block), you are changing the `sendMessage` function thats on the `tose` object and not the local definition of the function.

---

There are many different ways you could approach this, one of which is:

```
var modules = require('./modules');
var functions = {
  eventHandler: eventHandler,
  sendMessage: sendMessage,
};
console.log('[tose] Loading modules: ', Object.keys(modules));

function eventHandler(channel, type, data, react=()=>{}) {
  switch (type) {
    case 'new_message':
      console.log('[tose][new_message]', channel, 'from:', data.cid, 'message:', data.message);
      if (regexTemplates.testSearch.test(data.message.toLowerCase())) {
        ...
      } else {
        functions.sendMessage(channel, data.cid, data.message);    // Basic echo message
      }
      break;
  }
}

// The function to be stubbed
function sendMessage(channel, cid, message) {
  console.log('[tose][send_message]', channel, 'to:', cid, 'message:', message);
  coms[channel].sendMessage(cid, message); // Getting error here thus not really stubbed
}

module.exports = functions;
```

---

Note: `functions` is not a descriptive name - feel free to change it to something that is more meaningful.